# Subdirectory wordpress css not working properly

Tags: wordpress

I installed a WordPress site in the subdirectory and my CSS didn't work, but when I start my local XAMPP server then it works. I turn off my XAMPP and my CSS doesn't work again.

I changed my **site_url** and **home** in the **wp_options** , it still doesn't work.

Here is the **.htaccess** file :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /staging/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ staging[L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?paradiseexplorers.com$
RewriteRule . /staging/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Here is [my WordPress site](https://paradiseexplorers.com/staging/).

How can I fix it?

Comment: You'll need XAMPP (or any other development environment) running in order for WordPress to work. I sense that the PHP may not be getting compiled or not including the CSS files properly, but either way you'll need to leave XAMPP running.

Comment: thank you for helping me. I fixed it. I deactivated and then reactivated again and it worked perfectly.